# Google Geocode API ZIP Code used in result address

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, geocoding, google-geocoder

I am geocoding the site below through Google's geocode api and receiving some odd results.

I am sending an address to google to be geocoded and should be receiving back a candidate address with the best possible precision of route, but for some reason I am receiving back a candidate with a street_address precision. I looked into this site further and it looks like Google is using the zip code as part of the street address when geocoding. Does anyone know how this is happening and better yet how this can be avoided?

The address I am trying to geocode:
Rte 1   East Walpole    MA  02032   US

Url request:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Rte+1%20East+Walpole%20MA%202032%20US&sensor=false

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why do you think you should only be getting "the best possible precision of route"?

Comment: I am sending in an address of route 1. I should not be getting a street_address precision because how would you know if it is 123 Route 1 or 456 Route 1?

Comment: How do you expect the geocoder tell that?  It is biased towards returning a single address if possible, and apparently for that input it think that value is the best match.